# Can I "restore tabs" in Microsoft Edge from another user's profile?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, user-profiles, browser-tabs, session-restore

I had a new User Profile created for me, with the old User Profile still available and readable by me.

I am a bit hesitant about doing a "rough" Edge user data migration, of just copying the relevant folders under `AppData` (although perhaps I shouldn't be?) - but it is important to me to get the tabs which were open in the Edge windows last time I logged on to the old profile.

Is it possible to "restore" those tabs in my new profile's instance of Edge? If not, is it possible to at least extract their URLs into a text file?

Additional info:

- I have the previous profile's credentials.
- My profile is an Administrator.
- Windows version: Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.19045.4170
- The reason for the new profile creation is some kind of OS refresh/update and/or change of Domain - due to corporate procedure, not some technical problem.

Comment: Why did you need a new user profile ?

Comment: @harrymc: I didn't really... my company did some OS update/refresh, perhaps also with a "domain" change, and when I logged in using the same credentials it was a new profile.

Comment: Copy the Edge user profile directory to the new system, I routinely transfer Chromium based browsers profiles, between systems

Answer (score 1):

Edge [stores](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:docs/session_history.md?q=restore&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc:docs%2F) open tabs [within](https://www.foxtonforensics.com/browser-history-examiner/microsoft-edge-history-location) one or more `Tabs_<arbitrary #>` file(s) located at:

```bash
# See #4 for Old User's %LocalAppData% path
  "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Sessions\Tabs_<arbitrary #>"
```

---

To restore the old User Profile's Edge tabs for the current user, copy the `Tabs_<arbitrary #>` file(s) from the old User Profile to the new one:

1. **Open a Terminal:** <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open:* `powershell` → *OK*
2. **Close Microsoft Edge, then ensure no instances remain open:**

   ```powershell
   TaskKill /im "msedge.exe" /f
   ```
3. **Rename current Edge profile's `Tabs_<arbitrary #>` file(s) to `Tabs-<#>.old`:**

   ```powershell
   Ren "$env:LocalAppData\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Sessions\Tabs" "$env:LocalAppData\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Sessions\Tabs-<#>.old"
   ```

   - With cursor at the end of `..\Tabs`, double press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to auto-complete numerical portion of the file name, repeating until no more `Tabs_<arbitrary #>` file(s) exist
4. **Copy old User Profile's Edge profile's `Tabs_<arbitrary #>` file(s) to new user's:**

   ```powershell
   Xcopy "C:\Users\<OldUser>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Sessions\Tabs*" "$env:LocalAppData\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Sessions\"
   ```
5. **Open Edge**

---

To restore the old User Profile's Edge profile for the current user, copy the Edge profile's `User Data` directory from the old User Profile, instead of only the `Tabs_<arbitrary #>` file(s):

1. **Close Microsoft Edge, then ensure no instances remain open:**

   ```powershell
   TaskKill /im "msedge.exe" /f
   ```
2. **Rename current Edge profile's `User Data` directory to `User Data.old`:**

   ```powershell
   Ren "$env:LocalAppData\Microsoft\Edge\User Data" "$env:LocalAppData\Microsoft\Edge\User Data.old"
   ```
3. **Copy old user's Edge profile's `User Data` directory to new user:**

   ```powershell
   RoboCopy "C:\Users\<OldUser>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data" "$env:LocalAppData\Microsoft\Edge\User Data" /e /eta /v
   ```
4. **Open Edge**

Comment: This will make the new profile identical to the old (if there was a problem with that old profile).

Comment: @harrymc A new User Profile wouldn't have been created because of an issue with the Edge profile _(or at least it shouldn't have been)_

Comment: “It's unclear whether Edge restores tabs from this file” - All chromium based browsers store sessions and tabs identically.

Comment: @Ramhound Right, but I couldn't find any info regarding whether once Edge is closed, does a Chromium-based browser restore previously open tabs from `..\User Data\Default\Sessions\Tabs_<arbitrary #>`? It doesn't seem like they do, since if you force-close Edge with `TaskKill`, the previous open tabs aren't restored. Even searching the Chromium Developer help section only returned [this](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:docs/session_history.md?q=restore&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc:docs%2F) as relevant

Comment: @JW0914 - If you force close a Chromium process, it can't possibly go through the process of saving the sessions and/or tabs.  However, you should still be able to open those tabs (or their last saved state), by using the keyboard shortcut to do so.

Comment: @Ramhound What file does it save the last saved state to? Since open tabs are already saved in `Sessions\Tabs_<arbitrary #>`, that doesn't appear to be the file that is used to restore previously open tabs from, else upon re-opening the browser following a force close would auto re-open the tabs within `Sessions\Tabs_<arbitrary #>`.

Comment: Chrome will create new instances of the Tabs and Sessions file in the event of an unexpected closure of the Chrome processes. Normally, Chrome would save the session data to the session files and the your open tabs to the tab file. I have in the past restored closed tabs by putting the tabs file in Chrome user profile directory for the and hit the keyboard shortcut to open previous opened tabs.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks! I'm not on a machine I can test at the moment and as soon as I can test _(I don't like adding info to an answer until I've tested, otherwise it requires a disclaimer that I wasn't able to test)_, I'll update with those steps today or tomorrow at the latest